# How to plot a data.table with columns with lists

Tags: r, list, plot

Currently I have a data.table of this form:

```
USER    active  reason  days    # of elements by hour
4q7C0o  1   NA  28  c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 98, 167, 211, 246)
2BrKY63 1   NA  28  c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 15, 24, 89, 187) 
3drUy6I 1   NA  28  c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 112, 265, 309) 
G5ALtO  1   NA  28  c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 20, 153, 170)
```

Where in the column "#elements by hour" each list is 24 elements long (i ommited the rest just for clarity)

However I don know how to perform the 2 following things:

1) plot all the #elements by hour in a single plot and label them by "user" or "active" (something that appears like a time series)

2) apply a function also to the column "elements by hour"

I tried following but it gives nothing:

```
plotserieslines <- function(yvar){
     ggplot(tickets_by_hour_2019031, aes_(x=c(0:23) ,y=yvar)) +
         geom_line() 
 }
 lapply(names(tickets_by_hour_2019031[,#elements by hour,]), plotserieslines)
```

and $tickets_by_hour_2019031$ is my data.table

Comment: Is it a  `data.table` object or simply a data frame?

Comment: it is a $data.table$ object @NelsonGon

Comment: can you post the result of `dput(tickets_by_hour_2019031)`

Comment: ```structure(list(pos = "4q7C0o", usable = 1L, reason = NA_character_, 
    number_days = 28L, tickets_by_hour = list(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 5L, 98L, 167L, 211L, 246L, 250L, 290L, 332L, 351L, 
    324L, 337L, 310L, 299L, 337L, 404L, 481L, 108L, 0L)), tickets_by_hour_vector = list(
        c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 98L, 167L, 211L, 246L, 
        250L, 290L, 332L, 351L, 324L, 337L, 310L, 299L, 337L, 
        404L, 481L, 108L, 0L))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x560622341ef0>) ```